# Criteria for being able to work with gravity in quantum mechanics, without a full theory of quantum gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, quantum-gravity

It's common to see people oversimplify by saying that physics currently lacks the tools to describe any situation involving both quantum mechanics and gravity. Clearly this is not the case. For example, the Pound-Rebka experiment involves inescapably quantum-mechanical phenomena such as the Mossbauer effect, but is really just a test of the equivalence principle. Less trivially, Colella et al. did [an experiment](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.34.1472) demonstrating interference between two beams of neutrons that had traveled through different gravitational potentials. It seems to me that there are probably a bunch of different levels of difficulty we could consider:

1. Experiments, such as the ones above, involving quantum mechanics, that can be described in flat spacetime using the equivalence principle. Curvature of spacetime is negligible.
2. Experiments in which curvature is nonnegligible, but the analysis is still trivial. For example, I could imagine, at least in principle, doing gravitational lensing with neutrons and observing quantum interference effects between different parts of the beam. (In reality, I'd guess this example wouldn't work due to decoherence.)
3. Semiclassical gravity, e.g., Hawking radiation.
4. Planck-scale physics.

Can anyone comment on whether this 4-level classification seems right, or give a more rigorous set of criteria for distinguishing the levels?

Comment: Is [this](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.34.1472) the neutron experiment you were thinking of?

Comment: @jacob1729: Yep, that was it, thanks! I edited the reference into the question.

Comment: You could also include quantum mechanics on time-dependent metrics. Or do you also consider this to be trivial in the sense of 2?

Comment: How about LIGO type observational astronomy via gravitational waves? This is technology that's only just really begun given that they confirmed the discovery of gravitational waves just recently; but it seems plausible to me that this is likely to be an important window on quantum gravity effects in the future.

Comment: @MoziburUllah: As far as I know, LIGO is 100% classical physics. Mark Mitchison: In the context of classical relativity, I don't think the notion of a time-varying metric is very meaningful. You can make Minkowski space have a time-varying metric just by doing a change of coordinates. You can talk about coordinate-independent notions like static and stationary spacetimes, but these are definitions that depend on measures of curvature, not on the metric itself, which is not observable at a point.

Comment: Sure, most observational equipment of that size is going to be; anyway, have a look at [this](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2018/04/a-black-hole-merger-merger-merger.html?m=1) ('2.5 sigma evidence for QG').

Comment: @MoziburUllah: Interesting link, thanks. In general, I don't find it plausible when semiclassical gravity predicts violations of the equivalence principle, such as gee-whiz quantum effects at the event horizon of a black hole. It just smells like a case where they need to renormalize their calculations and didn't know how to do it properly. Semiclassical gravity is completely untested and unreliable. But of course if this 2.5 sigma observation becomes 5 sigma, that would be exciting.

Comment: @BenCrowell: Sure, It's very early days for LIGO type gravitational astronomy, they've only just after all detected these waves. It strikes me as pretty plausible (even if you don't) that smashing two massive black holes together is going to get us some kind of signal that will help experimentally evaluate the possibilities for quantum gravity. Semi-classical gravity may be untested but so was the Higgs boson, and so was gravitational waves; and besides before you can test a hypothesis or a conjecture you need one or two.

Comment: @BenCrowell What I'm getting at here is the interaction of quantum matter with gravitational waves. I thought this essentially means a time-dependent metric (and space-dependent, of course, although the relevant wavelengths are practically infinite for quantum systems). But perhaps this isn't the best way way to think about it. In any case, this seems to be a well posed problem to study, even if not directly relevant for LIGO.

Comment: BICEP2 almost gave us gravitons, except it fizzled out. They are persisting though.  see https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06755

Comment: Where would "Gravitational quantum physics" belong on this list?
http://iopscience.iop.org/journal/1367-2630/page/Focus%20on%20Gravitational%20Quantum%20Physics

Answer (score 2):

As you say, Colella et al already demonstrated (or confirmed, depending on one's perspective) that gravity affects a quantum system. Lately, there has been an effort to come up with an experimental apparatus that would exhibit the opposite: a gravitational effect from a quantum system in a low energy regime. Some of the thrust comes from the work by Bose et al; and Marletto and Vedral (conceived as "table-top" experiments).

Markus Aspelmeyer in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjSUF42F6qQ discusses some of the recent experimental approaches.

Re 2: I believe https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03832 goes towards it, showing the curvature-induced phase shift of an atomic wave.

Re 1 and 3: https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11494 has an overview of some of the newer proposals (in particular, how the outcomes of the experiments might disambiguate among varying quantum gravity contenders, in particular, falsification of semiclassical gravity if entanglement observed).

Re 4: This is probably a stretch for the foreseeable future. Jake Taylor discusses some of the difficulties in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDP5vL9OlaU.